# Copying onchange attribute from one element to another - how?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

using jquery 1.7...

I'm trying to copy all the attributes from the specified element, to the $to element; everything works great except for the onchange attribute (event). The id's get copied as well, but when I go to trigger the change() on the new element, I get the following .js error, even if I re-add the change handler, it fails although if I call change() a second time, it works any ideas?:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'apply' 
jquery-1.7.2.min.js, line 3 character 3463

```
  var $to = $("#Someelement");
    var attributes = $("#AssignmentStatusIdNew").prop("attributes");
    $("#AssignmentStatusIdNew").remove();

     // loop through <select> attributes and apply them to $to...
                $.each(attributes, function () {
                    if (window.jqueryMinorVersion >= 6) {
                        $to.prop(this.name, this.value);
                    } else {
                        $to.attr(this.name, this.value);
                    }
                });

$("#AssignmentStatusIdNew").change(AssignmentStatusId_ValueUpdated);
    $("#AssignmentStatusIdNew").change();
```

Comment: Why not just clone the element: `var $to = $('#Someelement').clone(true, true);`? See [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Comment: this is actually a repeat question:

check out this stack post Jquery onchange event for cloned field